# Can I use Widgets from support library of Android L Preview in current Android Version?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to use RecyclerView & CardView in existing Android version. They said it is in support library. So, I should be able to use those with put "compileSdkVersion" to "Android-L". Right ?

I am trying to use those widgets without Android L Preview device or emulator.I have checked other questions on this matter. But, seems they all are trying Android-L with Android-L version.

Here is my dependencies.

> compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
>   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'

Here is my target config

> minSdkVersion 15
>   targetSdkVersion 20

Thanks in advance for any idea.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just found the solution.
The reason why I can't build the App with RecyclerView & CardView while the **targetSdkVersion** and **minSdkVersion** is not **"Android-L"** is because internally Google designed to treat the preview version of OS differently comparing with original releases.

When I compile the App which contains the components from Android-L, the build tools locked **minSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** to same level. The new supports libraries (RecyclerView, CardView, Palette, etc) are also locked into the L API level.

*This behaviour is only happening on this Android-L preview release*.

The fix for it is to put the following in AndroidManifest.xml.
I didn't need to change anything on my gradle script.

```
<uses-sdk
  tools:node="replace" />
```

Since version 0.11 of Android Gradle Plugin, it turned on a new Manifest Merger by default. It allows us to do some niffy stuffs. This specific configuration tells the manifest processor to replace any attributes from uses-sdk nodes in lower-priority manifest (such as library manifest in this case) with this attributes.

Since Gradle also inserts minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from your build.gradle into this uses-sdk node, that's all we really need to add.

Check [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_versions/) for more information related to this issue.
Check [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger) for the info related to Manifest Merger.

Comment: Can you please share a tiny project that uses RecyclerView and works even on pre-Android-L versions?

Comment: This isn't the safest thing to do. The real problem is that you might accidentally add a dependence that really does have a min version that is greater then yours and with no warning. You could then publish something that just blows up once it gets on the PlayStore.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is [RecyclerViewLib](https://github.com/twotoasters/RecyclerViewLib). The support library has been pulled into a repo and published on maven central. It'll be safe even after L is released as all L dependent code has been removed. The author explains it here in his [blog post](http://toastdroid.com/2014/09/03/unlocking-recyclerview/).

To use it in your project just add the following line in your build.gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.twotoasters.RecyclerViewLib:library:1.0.+@aar'
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No you must set targetSdkVersion above 7. You can use android support library v7 with project that support android above 7 api level.
And one more. Android L has api level 'android-L', not 20. Under the hood it has api level 21 (20 is 4.4W, KitKat for wearables).

Comment: So, if i put targetSdkVersion to "7" those RecyclerView & CardView suppose to work in device which doesn't have Android-L installed ?

Comment: This is what the gradle script is saying.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1

Comment: @AungPyae You can't publish app with android-target sdk android-L in google play now. So, you can't use android support library release candidate in your project. RecycleView contains in support library v7. Do use something from support-v4:21?

Comment: @AungPyae If you use, so you can set targetSdkVersion to "android-L" and it will work on android without android-L installed, but you can't use features form android-L, because your older android will crash on it

Comment: I understand I can't publish App with "L" in GooglePlay now. The nature of a widget in support library is the targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion doesn't need to match with the version the widget got released. Even though I use targetSdkVersion to 7 and minSdkVersion to 7, those RecyclerView and CardView are supposed to work perfectly. Even on device with OS as low as Gingerbread. Anyway, thanks for your responses. I just found the solution.